# Xdebug stopped connecting to PhpStorm in multi-versioned PHP Vagrant

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, phpstorm-2017.2

I was using a really old Homestead version 2.0 with PHP 7.0 and Xdebug enabled. When I upgraded to Homestead 7.0.1 which supports multiple versions of PHP running at the same time, Xdebug stopped connecting to PhpStorm 2017.

The configuration in PhpStorm is the same as before the Homestead upgrade.

I copied my original `xdebug.ini` into the new PHP 7.1 ini for Xdebug. Here is my current config:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10
xdebug.default_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.10.1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.collect_return = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 10
xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_profiler"
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_traces"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.trace_enable = 1
xdebug.cli_color = 1
xdebug.remote_log = "/home/vagrant/Projects/logs/xdebug_remote.log"
```

If I run `php -m` I see Xdebug is not in that list because Homestead 7 makes PHP 7.2 the default, which is incompatible with Xdebug as of this post. However, if I do `php7.1 -m` I see Xdebug in the list and `php7.1 -v` shows:

```
with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

So I know Xdebug is installed properly.

PhpStorm's prefs show it is using the 7.1 interpreter on Vagrant and that it is able to successfully connect to Vagrant. I manually navigated to the `xdebug.so` file on vagrant thru PhpStorm's UI just to be sure it could find it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Running CLI scripts by doing `php7.1 artisan` explicitly instead of `php artisan` does not help.

This inconsistently shows up in my `/home/vagrant/Projects/logs/xdebug_remote.log` but most of the time there is no remote log entry:

```
Log opened at 2018-01-17 17:50:46
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.10.1:9001.
W: Creating socket for '192.168.10.1:9001', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-01-17 17:50:46
```

Why can't PhpStorm receive signals from Xdebug on Vagrant anymore?

Comment: 1) If you have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` then `xdebug.remote_host` will be ignored (at least for web requests). 2) More importantly -- why do you have `xdebug.default_enable = 0`? Often it does not work with the `0` value (not sure about your case though)... 3) In any case: use `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` and xdebug should be trying to debug every single script (or place `xdebug_break()` in your code). So far, based on your description, it could be that you do not use the right PHP version...

Comment: @LazyOne setting `xdebug.default_enable = 1` and `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in the `xdebug.ini` didn't fix the problem. How do I tell which PHP version is correct and enable that?

Comment: Is xdebug log still empty? With `remote_autostart=1` it should be generating it even for CLI execution (e.g. you execute some script via SSH or even cron task -- as long as it uses that PHP). Xdebug log is the key here. TBH I do not know what else to suggest right now.

Comment: @LazyOne finally got something to show in the logs but it's inconsistent. Not every time I add a breakpoint in PHPStorm. Added it to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I need to set PHP 7.1 as the default instead of PHP 7.2. This was done by running this series of commands and then reconnecting too Xdebug within PHPStorm:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.1 
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.1
sudo service php7.1-fpm restart
```